# Solving a second order ODE numerically

Tags: differential-equations, numerics

I am trying to solve the following second order linear ODE numerically (for small w, say)

```
y''[x]+ D[f[x],x]/f[x] y'[x]+ w^2/(x^2 f[x])^2 y[x] == 0
```

where, `f[x_]:= (1 + 3 (x/x0)^4 - 4(x/x0)^3) /x^2`

The boundary conditions are

1. `y[0] = 1`
2. `y[x0] = Exp[-I (x0^2 w)/(6(x-x0))]`

Can someone suggest an easy way to solve it. I am particularly worried about the 2nd boundary condition. Don't understand how to impose it. Any useful reference(s) will be very helpful too. Thanks in advance.

EDIT : The 2nd boundary condition is a bit misleading. We can impose it at `x=x0+a` where a is very small number. The boundary condition can also be modified as `y'[x0+a]/y[x0+a]= -I (x0 w) /(6 a^2)`

Comment: It's unclear why `x`, the dependent variable, is in the second boundary condition.

Comment: Yes. Actually more concretely its the *behavior* of y[x] near x=x0 rather than the value of y[x] *at* x=x0.

Comment: @Pillsy I have added a "new" boundary condition which is almost equivalent to the previous one. Please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: @JackLaVigne Please check my edited boundary condition. There are only x0 and w. This w can be arbitrarily small and x0 ~ 1 0r 10.

Comment: @JackLaVigne 10-6 is fair. :)

Comment: I tried that. It worked. Actually one needs to put the boundary condition as : y'[x0+a] =  #  y[x0+a].

Comment: If you have solved this you should post the solution as an answer.